# How to create lists of 3x3 sudoku block in python

Tags: python, list, sudoku

I need help creating a list for each of the 9 3x3 blocks in sudoku. so I have a list of lists representing the original sudoku board (zero means empty):

```
board=[[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0],
       [0,0,0,0,7,5,0,3,0],
       [0,4,8,0,9,0,1,0,0],
       [0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0],
       [3,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,9],
       [0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0],
       [0,0,1,0,2,0,5,7,0],
       [0,8,0,7,3,0,0,0,0],
       [0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,4]]
```

I need to turn these into a list of lists containing the 3x3 blocks. So for example:

```
[[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,8],[etc]]
```

i tried creating one list called "blocks" containing 9 other lists with just zeroes in each list. so it looked like:

```
blocks=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[etc]
```

then i used a while loop to change the values in the list:

```
BLOCK_COUNT=0
BOARD_COUNT=0
while BLOCK_COUNT<len(blocks):
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][0]=board[BOARD_COUNT][BOARD_COUNT]
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][1]=board[BOARD_COUNT][BOARD_COUNT+1]
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][2]=board[BOARD_COUNT][BOARD_COUNT+2]
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][3]=board[BOARD_COUNT+1][BOARD_COUNT]
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][4]=board[BOARD_COUNT+1][BOARD_COUNT+1]
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][5]=board[BOARD_COUNT+1][BOARD_COUNT+2]
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][6]=board[BOARD_COUNT+2][BOARD_COUNT]
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][7]=board[BOARD_COUNT+2][BOARD_COUNT+1]
    blocks[BLOCK_COUNT][8]=board[BOARD_COUNT+2][BOARD_COUNT+2]
    BLOCK_COUNT+=1
    BOARD_COUNT+=3
```

This however gives me an index error. if I create 2 of those while loops with "BLOCK_COUNT" being 3 and 6 respectively then i get a better answer but it still doesn't give me the correct 3x3 block for some. So i'm pretty much at a loss for how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: If you want us to debug your error, please give us the full error and traceback, not just a description of the error.

Comment: no as i said I need help creating the lists of 3x3 blocks. I just gave the info on the errors thinking that it might be useful to know where i'm going wrong. I'm assuming it wasn't needed?

Comment: Because you didn't give us enough information to debug your code, everyone ignored that part of it and wrote brand-new code for you instead. The brand-new code is probably better—at least if you can understand it—but wouldn't it have been helpful to know where you went wrong as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def getBlocks(board):
    answer = []
    for r,c in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2):
        answer.append([board[r+i][c+j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(0, 9, 3), repeat=2)])
    return answer
```

Of course, you could replace the whole thing with just one list comprehension:

```
answer = [[board[r+i][c+j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(0, 9, 3), repeat=2)]
          for r,c in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)]
```

In case you are interested in a version that doesn't use any built-ins to do any heavy lifting:

```
def getBlocks(board):
    answer = []
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(3):
            block = []
            for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    block.append(board[3*r + i][3*c + j])
            answer.append(block)
    return answer
```

**So what's happening here?**:

Well, first, we decide to iterate over the 9 blocks that we want. These are governed by the `r` and `c` variables. This is also why we multiply them by 3 when we access the numbers on the board (because each block is a square of side 3).

Next, we want to iterate over the elements in each block. Translation: Lookup the numbers within each 3x3 block. The index of each element within the block is governed by `i` and `j`. So we have `i` and `j` that govern the elements we want to access, along with `r` and `c`, which are their offsets from the board itself, determining the location of the "block" we want. Now we're off to the races.

For each `r` and `c` (notice that each loops over `range(3)`, so there are 9 `(r,c)` pairs - the 9 blocks that we are after), loop over the 9 elements in the block (the 9 `(i,j)` pairs). Now, simply access the elements based on their relative locations from the `(r,c)` offsets (`3*r` gives the first row of the relevant block, and adding `i` gives the row of the required element. Similarly, `3*c` gives the first column of the relevant block, and adding `j` gives the column of the required element. Thus, we have the coordinates of the element we want). Now, we add the element to `block`.

Once we've looped over all the elements in the block, we add the block itself to the answer, and presto! we're done

Comment: This would be better with an explanation. Also, for a novice, it might be simpler to use nested loops than `product`. (Still better than what I was about to post, where I used a 3-line comprehension over comprehensions…)

Comment: Ack, now you've added my comprehension, but crammed into 2 lines instead of 3. :) But fortunately, you showed the more novice-friendly version first.

Comment: Sorry @abarnert, I just love list-comps wayy too much

Comment: Well, I love genexprs too much. I debated writing it as a nested genexpr in case you're just going to iterate over each block once (which seems likely, since you're going to have to recompute them every time the board changes, and what else are you going to do with them but iterate them?), then explaining why you have to `print([list(block) for block in blocks])` if you want to actually see the results, then…

Comment: While you're adding helpful alternatives… I think mhleister's deleted answer is easy to read—and, while it gives the wrong result, showing how to flatten that to the right result with `chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(…))` or a nested comp might be handy.

Comment: @abarnert: what do you think of the explanation in the latest edit

Comment: The formatting (no blank lines between paragraphs) is a little painful to read… but once you get past that, very complete, and doesn't seem to assume anything a novice wouldn't immediately understand. Too bad I can't +1 this again. :)

Comment: One last thing: What about `r in range(0, 9, 3)` so you can drop the `3 *` (and the explanation of it)? Easier to explain to a novice, or harder?

Comment: @abarnert: I thought about that, but I figured that was akin to using `itertools.product` in that it "does some heavy lifting for you". The multiplication lets OP see exactly what's happening. Perhaps, I should use `range(0,9,3)` in one of the list comprehensions, to show that it would make work easier

Comment: Nah, I don't think you need to show every possible alternative way to do each piece of this. Anyone who tries to follow up on your explanations by reading the tutorial will probably figure them out on his own, and, if not, the comments are here. It's more than good enough an answer as-is.

Comment: Thank you. especially for the explanation. this works really well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a combination of `reshape` and `transpose` when you use `numpy`.

**edit** - sorry - hit enter too soon:

```
import numpy as np
board=[[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0],
       [0,0,0,0,7,5,0,3,0],
       [0,4,8,0,9,0,1,0,0],
       [0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0],
       [3,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,9],
       [0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0],
       [0,0,1,0,2,0,5,7,0],
       [0,8,0,7,3,0,0,0,0],
       [0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,4]]

t = np.array(board).reshape((3,3,3,3)).transpose((0,2,1,3)).reshape((9,9));
print t
```

Output:

```
[[2 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 8]
 [0 0 0 0 7 5 0 9 0]
 [0 6 0 0 3 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0]
 [3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 8]
 [0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 8 0 0 9 0]
 [0 2 0 7 3 0 0 0 0]
 [5 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## should work, in python3 you might replace "(m/3)*3" with "int(m/3)*3"

```
[[board[(m/3)*3+i][(m%3)*3+j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)] for m in range(9)]
```

Comment: This raises **list indices must be integers, not float**  exception in python 3.4  due to the fact the division m/2 produces a float and not and int. so that, it should be m//3 in order to produce the floor of the division.

Answer (score 0):

**this uses no builtins and is faster 3 nested for loops**

```
def get_boxes(board):
    boxes = []
    for i in range(9): 
        if i == 0 or i % 3 == 0:  
            box_set_1 = board[i][:3] + board[i + 1][:3] + board[i + 2][:3]  
            boxes.append(box_set_1)
            box_set_2 = board[i][3:6] + board[i + 1][3:6] + board[i + 2][3:6]
            boxes.append(box_set_2)
            box_set_3 = board[i][6:] + board[i + 1][6:] + board[i + 2][6:]
            boxes.append(box_set_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_boxes(board):    
    boxes = []
    for i in range(9): 
        if i == 0 or i % 3 == 0:  
            box_set_1 = board[i][:3] + board[i + 1][:3] + board[i + 2][:3]  
            boxes.append(box_set_1)
            box_set_2 = board[i][3:6] + board[i + 1][3:6] + board[i + 2][3:6]
            boxes.append(box_set_2)
            box_set_3 = board[i][6:] + board[i + 1][6:] + board[i + 2][6:]
            boxes.append(box_set_3)
    return boxes
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicated answers. Edit the one answer to include any differences. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).