# Formating Sudoku Grids Python 3

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, formatting, sudoku

So basically, I'm trying to use Python 3 to create a sudoku solver by implementing backtracking as a learning project, so I'm not going for perfect efficiency yet (I'm going to rewrite it afterwards to try to get it better, I have redundant variables and other random stuff used), just getting it to work. However while I'm working on it, debugging is getting to be a challenge, and I want to format the grid I'm using better as it goes along, however I don't really know how to do so. This is how I'm storing it right now:

```
grid = [
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 8],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 4, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
[9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 7, 0],
[0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 7],
[6, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

But I want to output it in this sort of format:

```
-------------------------------------
| 4         |         5 |           |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|           |           | 1   9   8 |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
| 3         |     8   2 | 4         |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|           | 1         |     8     |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
| 9       3 |           |           |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|           |     3     | 6   7     |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|     5     |         9 |           |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
|           | 2         | 9       7 |
|   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   |
| 6   4     | 3         |           |
-------------------------------------
```

(including changing the 0s into blank spaces)

Right now I'm just using pprint.pprint to print it out, but it's getting challenging. As a total programming noob, how do I format the grid that way efficiently?

EDIT:
Could I know why I'm getting downvoted? I made my account a few minutes ago to ask this question, but I think I have provided enough information, and I can't find this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I was just using a formatting style I came across on the internet.

Comment: I believe you were downvoted because you do not show any code of your own. Just stating you have some code is not enough. Please show us what you have done. Also, you have not defined "efficiently": Pythonic, few lines of code, small memory use, quick speed, or other? Also, your two examples do not correspond to each other. Also, printing varies between Python 2.x and 3.x. Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: Sorry, when I mean it isn't efficient, I mean it's sort of a mess, not really commented, structure that would probably make an experienced programmer cringe, redundant variables etc.. I'm using python 3. I'll add some of these things to the body.

Comment: I've looked at things like https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html, but I have no idea how they work or how to use them

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270501/how-to-create-lists-of-3x3-sudoku-block-in-python?rq=1 too

Comment: @m4ge, it'll help the folks here to address your concerns if you post your code. When you feel more confident with your program, you might also consider submitting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Likewise, a noob - some good advice I got early on: don't need the backstory, just the code and your question, e.g. "How can I format this list so it prints like this (a sudoku board). Here's my code: "?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy thanks, this was my first question here, and I just wanted to make sure that I'm giving enough information.

Comment: @Jean-MichelProvencher This isn't a duplicate, if you read both my question and that question, you can see that they are asking about creating variables for each of the 9 cell squares, while I'm asking how to format a list.

Comment: @m4ge certainly. Often just writing out a question helps to clarify my thinking about a problem, but I now do a "reduction" pass prior to posting here :) You might also find that if you edit your post accordingly, negs have a way of becoming positive ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I'd prepare the output you want:

```
def print_sudoku(board):
    print("-"*37)
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        print(("|" + " {}   {}   {} |"*3).format(*[x if x != 0 else " " for x in row]))
        if i == 8:
            print("-"*37)
        elif i % 3 == 2:
            print("|" + "---+"*8 + "---|")
        else:
            print("|" + "   +"*8 + "   |")
```

There are three key parts.

The first is to use `enumerate` to iterate over the rows of the board and get the index of each row along with it. We need the index to tell how the line after the row should be formatted.

The next key bit is getting rid of the zeros. I use a list comprehension `[x if x != 0 else " " for x in row]` which replaces each `0` with a one-space string. It now occurrs to me that `x or " "` would be a more concise (but less readable, perhaps) way of doing `x if x != 0 else " "`.

The last tricky bit is the string formatting. Rather than writing out the string:

```
 "| {}   {}   {} | {}   {}   {} | {}   {}   {} |"
```

in full, I've used string concatenation and repetition to create it more concisely:

```
 ("|" + " {}   {}   {} |"*3)
```

This is used as the format string for `str.format`, which plugs in one value from the list comprehension in place of each `{}`.

You could simplify things a bit if were willing to have plus signs in the outer border:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4         |         5 |           |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|           |           | 1   9   8 |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
| 3         |     8   2 | 4         |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|           | 1         |     8     |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
| 9       3 |           |           |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|           |     3     | 6   7     |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|     5     |         9 |           |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|           | 2         | 9       7 |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
| 6   4     | 3         |           |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

is produced by:

```
def print_sudoku2(board):
    print("+" + "---+"*9)
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        print(("|" + " {}   {}   {} |"*3).format(*[x if x != 0 else " " for x in row]))
        if i % 3 == 2:
            print("+" + "---+"*9)
        else:
            print("+" + "   +"*9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you please explain how the code actually works? I see how the last if statement works, but I don't understand 2 things: how for loop iterates, and how "print(("|" + " {}   {}   {} |"*3).format(*[x if x != 0 else " " for x in row]))" works

Comment: I've edited with a more detailed explanation of the subtle bits of the code.

Comment: @m4ge look about a third of the way down the page for, "Basic usage of the str.format() method looks like this:" from https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html